# How to set wildcard reverse proxy in Nginx

Tags: nginx

Suppose you have a request for the following json file.

e.g. https://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc.json

I want to have Nginx handle **'aaa'** as a **fixed** string, and **'bbb'** and **'ccc'** as **changing** strings.

In this case, I want the proxy to work ignoring the **'bbb'** path in the URL.
How should I describe this in a lcoation block in Nginx?

```
location /aaa {
   # I want to ignore 'bbb' path and return ccc.json. 'ccc' varies.
   alias /mydirectory/aaa;
   try_files $url;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locations in nginx can be defined with regular expressions ([docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)).

Depending on how specific you'd like to be, you might choose `~` for case-sensitive URI matching or `~*` for case-insensitive URI matching. `^~` is also available as a prefix match, but note a match here will stop the engine from performing additional regex matching. Caveat emptor.

Something like this would be a relatively straightforward way to "absorb" the `bbb` (or any other combo of 1 or more letters, upper and lower case):

```
location ~ ^\/aaa\/[a-zA-Z]+ {
  ...
}
```

In order to capture the `ccc.json`, you'll want to add a capturing group as well:

```
location  ~ ^\/aaa\/[a-zA-Z]+\/([\w\.]+) {
    return 200 '$1';
}
```

Bonus: if you're using PCRE 7+ ([docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names)), you can name your capture:

```
location  ~ ^\/aaa\/[a-zA-Z]+\/(?<filename>[\w\.]+) {
    return 200 '$filename';
}
```